# Mod_Rewrite not supporting empty strings

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am writing a web app for work that uses mod_rewrite in apache 2.4.
At the present I have it running at http://localhost:8080 and the site has two get virables 'product' and 'filter'.

I have the following rewrite rule that works:
<sup>RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?product=$1&$filter=$2 [L,QSA,NC]</sup>

This allows for someone to go to http://localhost:8080/productA/3 to get version 3 of product a.
But if they want all versions of productA I want them to goto http://localhost:8080/productA and leave the filter virable empty.

As it stands I get a 404 when going to http://localhost:8080/productA

Can someone help me out?

Thanks

John

I was trying to get /productA/ to go rewrite to index.php?product=producta&filter=